# Issue with JSONDecoder and Structs (API Call)

Tags: json, swift, struct

So I'm having another problem with JSON Decoder when parsing the data from an API. I'm getting the error "Error Parsing JSON". I am calling this api point: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=Science&apiKey=afd219a70f3d47f784e588548c0f7810

Here is my code where I am making the call:

```
        
        var baseURL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=\(category)&apiKey=afd219a70f3d47f784e588548c0f7810"

        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
          let request = URLRequest(url: url)
          let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
              print("error: ", error!)
              return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
              print("No data object")
              return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
              print("response is: ", response!)
              return
            }

            guard let mime = response?.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
              print("Wrong MIME type!")
              return
            }
            
            guard let articles = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleList.self, from: data) else {
              print("Error Parsing JSON")
              return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.articles = articles.articles
                print(self.articles)
            }
            
          }
          dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
```

And here are my structs:

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct ArticleList: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

// MARK: - Article
struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let articleDescription: String?
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: Date
    let content: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source, author, title
        case articleDescription = "description"
        case url, urlToImage, publishedAt, content
    }
}

// MARK: - Source
struct Source: Codable {
    let id: JSONNull?
    let name: String
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

I'm assuming there's something wrong with my structs, which is strange as I got them from quicktype.io. Any ideas?

Comment: In your two previous question regarding json decoding I have told you how to handle decoding errors but you just don’t care, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I also think it can be something with the structs. To verify your problem with the parse, try this:

remove this part of the code:

```
guard let articles = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleList.self, from: data) else {
              print("Error Parsing JSON")
              return
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.articles = articles.articles
       print(self.articles)
}
```

and use this:

```
do {
    let articles = try JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleList.self, from: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.articles = articles.articles
         print(self.articles)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will show you the errors parsing on the log window. The json is big, so it could be more than one. The parse error should be because some models are returning with some variables as null.

A way to fix this is to accept some variables as optional. like this:

```
struct ArticleList: Codable {
    let status: String?
    let totalResults: Int?
    let articles: [Article]?
}
```

But the best way is for you to know which ones are optional. Testing the api and reading the log for the parse error will help you with that.

One problem that I saw right away is your variable `Article.publishedAt` it returns a string like this: `2021-03-01T14:14:00Z` so the correct object is String, not Date. You would have to convert it later to date after the parse.

Comment: Thank you! Much more informative now. Here is what the error it spit out: Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "publishedAt", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0):

> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "publishedAt", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

The error clearly states that the value for key `publishedAt` in the array `articles` is not a `Double` (the default date decoding strategy), it's an ISO8601 `String`

You have to specify the proper date decoding strategy (I *pirated* the base code from Felipe's answer), and yes, **use always a `do - catch` block**

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let articles = try decoder.decode(ArticleList.self, from: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.articles = articles.articles
         print(self.articles)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Side notes:

- You don't need the `URLRequest`, there is a data task method with the same syntax taking an URL.
- Delete the `JSONNull` stuff and declare `id` in `Source` as `String?`